# reailsのコントローラーで取得したハッシュのvalueをviewで取り出して表示する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, json, erb

DBに`{"params": {"name": "apple", "color": "red"}`のようにデータが入っています。
これについて、railsのview上で"apple"や"red"のようなハッシュのvalueを取得する方法を教えて欲しいです。
おそらくjson形式のデータなので、`JSON.parse({"params": {"name": "apple", "color": "red"})`とすれば、
`{"name": "apple", "color": "red"}`が取得できるのですが、
`JSON.parse({"params": {"name": "apple", "color": "red"}})["name"]`としても"apple"を表示できません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

```rb
h = {"params": {"name": "apple", "color": "red"}}
h.dig :params, :name # => "apple"
```

これでできますでしょうか。`dig`は上記のようなネストしたハッシュから値を取得するためのメソッドです。